# MySQL Update Statement doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql

My update statement in MySQL doesn't appear to be working:

```
timeup = "UPDATE timeid set time=\"" + str(timeid) + "\""
c.execute(timeup)
```

I've tried everything I thought might be wrong with it, including changing the type of the variable (as you can see above, I have it as a string) and using and not using quotes.

I can even print out what the statement turns into:

```
UPDATE timeid set time="224215313716215808"
```

The only column and value that timeid has is time and 0, respectively.

Why isn't this updating? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
c.commit();
```

since `MySQLdb` begins a transaction for update statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
timeup = "UPDATE `timeid` SET `time`='" + str(timeid) + "';"
c.execute(timeup)
```

Time might be a constant in SQL and therefore using the simple quotation marks (I don't know, how they are called) ensures that you refer to a field. And try to use `'` for setting the value and consider adding a semicolon.

Did you select a database before?

Comment: Yes, database is selected.

I've changed my query to this: 

timeup = "UPDATE `timeid` set `timestamp`='" + str(timeid) + "';"

Comment: I do not know python, but maybe there is a function, which can give you some more detailled information about a possible error being returned by the MySQL-database.

Comment: I can't find any, tragically. This problem seems unsolvable to me - everything I'm doing seems to be right.

Comment: Does the same query you have the output of (`UPDATE timeid set time="224215313716215808"`) work using any other software, like phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a semicolon (;) at the end of the query and tell me if it works.